# using php session variable within mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to build a lookup field on a php form.

The application is a multi company database and in this scenario i am trying to build a document register, later i will set it so that only companies can see their own documentation etc.

In the past I have always had a template table that contains all the common document types, e.g. policy, procedure, etc, and then had a client document type table, that when a new client was added it would copy the data from the master table and help them build their own, that way when adding a document, the document type lookup would just point to their own table.

I am now trying to be a little smarted and setting a look up field that selects if the company FK is equal to either 0, or the company PK that they log in, for further clarification, company 0 is what I am using as baseline data, and I have a session variable that captures the company PK of the user that logs on, so in theory the combo can produce a list that looks up generic data from 0 or anything that this specific company has added.

This is the code I have in my current application:

```
SELECT
DocumentTypePk,
CompanyFk,
DocumentType,
AddedBy
FROM TemplateDocumentType
WHERE (CompanyFk=0 OR CompanyFk="{$_SESSION['Company']}")
```

Note that this is not a PHP injection, it is the actual MySQL Database, as if trying to run this from PHPmy Admin. I am comfortable with the concepts of using php to update/insert within mysql etc , e.g. ."'Session['whatever']'"

But this problem seems to be the other way around, I cannot get mysql database to take a php session variable.

Is this possible, am i missing something, or is there another way?

I am not getting any errors when running the actual form, but it is just returning everything within the table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already tried to var_dump() the contents of the $_SESSION['Company'] contents? If that returns what you expect, you can safely inject it into the MySQL database. However, please use prepared statements instead of direct injection.

Comment: just done that now, I am logged in with a user account assigned to company ID 1, and vardump result is string(1) "1"

Comment: can you please explain or provide an example of what you mean by prepared statement?

Comment: Well, in that case that would be what you expect and you can safely use the value in your query. For more information on how to do that with PHP you can have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp for example

Comment: thanks just had a look at that, but waaaay beyond me, if you could provide a quick example of what code should look like i would be eternally greatful :)

Comment: Session variables only exist in the PHP application, you can't refer to them from other applications like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: is your SQL statement surround by single quotes or a heardoc?

Comment: ok was starting to think that it wasnt possible, is there a work around other than needing two tables?

Comment: Do you already have a database connection set-up in your PHP file?

Comment: yes i do...............

Comment: Please show us the fullcode where you are building your SQL Query. This is important to know about which library you are using to connect to mysql and which type of quotation mark you are using to build your string.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that incorrect quotation marks are the problem.

Ensure you are using the right quotation marks when you are trying to inject variables into strings.

*This answer will change if we find out you are usinging MYSQLI or PDO*

```
$sql = 'SELECT
DocumentTypePk,
CompanyFk,
DocumentType,
AddedBy
FROM TemplateDocumentType
WHERE (CompanyFk=0 OR CompanyFk="' . $_SESSION['Company'] . '")';
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT
DocumentTypePk,
CompanyFk,
DocumentType,
AddedBy
FROM TemplateDocumentType
WHERE (CompanyFk=0 OR CompanyFk=\"{$_SESSION['Company']}\")";
```

or

```
$sql = <<<SQLSTATEMENT
SELECT
DocumentTypePk,
CompanyFk,
DocumentType,
AddedBy
FROM TemplateDocumentType
WHERE (CompanyFk=0 OR CompanyFk="{$_SESSION['Company']}")
SQLSTATEMENT;
```

Comment: Thanks I couldnt get it to work, so approached it with PHP, e.g. " CompanyFk = 0 or " . $_SESSION["Company"], and it works like a charm